# Forward Engineering ERD to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, reverse-engineering, mysql-workbench

The free edition of MySQL Wrokbench does not support the Forward/Reverse engineering functions to translate from ERD to schema and vise versa. Is there anything free out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get the exact meaning of what you are asking. But what I do know is that both the GPL and the entreprise version of MySQL Workbench have the same functionality.